# Can't execute mingw toolchain provided by Rtools

Tags: wine, r, mingw

I can't execute `R CMD INSTALL` on an installation of R + Rtools in Wine
(latest version from `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`). A reproducible script and
console output can be found here: https://gist.github.com/krlmlr/7333242 . The
script will set and write to `$WINEPREFIX` and download to `$DOWNLOAD_DIR`.

Unfortunately, the logs do not show enough detail. After the line `about to run
R CMD SHLIB -o kimisc.dll rcpp_hello_world.cpp RcppExports.cpp --debug`, a call
to `gcc` is made. (I have added the output of the same call on my Linux system
to the Gist.) To me, it seems that the calling process is not notified when the
child process has completed, and it stops after a timeout. My hope is that this
has been seen before and that there's an easy fix. I'm really new to Wine.

NB: I have filed a [bug report](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34865) but didn't get a reply yet. Cross-posting here hoping that this can be worked around easily, and that it's not a bug in Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug report has been answered.